# Add Tableview cell from a xib file in a static tablebview Controller which is being loaded from a storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am working on a Tableview Controller inside which is being loaded from inside a storyboard file.

For the purpose of reusability, I would like one of the cells in the storyboard to load from a nib file.

How can I do that?

My current implementation only uses viewDidLoad and none of the other tableview delegate methods

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

     self.title = self.requestTypeDescription;

self.itemDescriptionLabel.text = self.currentItem.articleDescription;
    self.modelNumberLabel.text = self.currentItem.partNumber;

  notesHistoryString =  @"Valerie is a young woman who lives...";
    self.partNumberCell.count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.currentItem.sapCount];
    self.serialNumbersCell.count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.currentItem.serialNumbers.count];



}
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Post the code that you have tried using. What do you mean "cells in the storyboard to load from a nib file"?

Comment: I have created a storyboard. Inside the storyboard is a tableview controller with a bunch of static cells. Now I would like to programmatically add one extra tableviewcell in it, but I don't want to create it in the storyboard. I want to create it inside a xib file of UItableviewCell so I dont have to built it in the storyboard again and again for other view controllers in other static tableviews that use the same kind of cell. Does that help explain my approach?

Comment: Not sure why I was down voted, just because I am thinking of a non-conventional approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a blank cell in the storyboard for the tableview inside the Tableview Controller(TVC). Then I created a nib file for a UIView .

My View, which is loading the nib has initWithFrame (for loading the xib), its implementation looks like this:

```
    @implementation SimpleView

    -(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {

        NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleView"
                                                              owner:nil
                                                            options:nil];

        if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1){
            return nil;
        }

        SimpleView *newView = [arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0];
        [newView setFrame:frame];
        self = newView;

        return self;

    }
```

Then on viewDidLoad inside the TVC, I added it inside the blank cell as follows:

```
@implementation ExistingRequestsItemDetailActionVC




#pragma mark - Life cycle
- (void) viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

     self.title = self.requestTypeDescription;

self.itemDescriptionLabel.text = self.currentItem.articleDescription;
    self.modelNumberLabel.text = self.currentItem.partNumber;

  notesHistoryString =  @"Valerie is a young woman who lives...";
    self.partNumberCell.count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.currentItem.sapCount];
    self.serialNumbersCell.count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.currentItem.serialNumbers.count];

// Here is where I am loading the other cellview from xib


    SimpleView *myView = [[SimpleView alloc] initWithFrame:self.myCell.bounds];

    myView.slider.value=1;

    [self.myCell addSubview:myView];


}
```

Comment: It is not the perfect solution I was looking for but does the job

Answer (score 0):

Register the nib with registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: (in viewDidLoad is a good place), and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, dequeue a cell with the same identifier you passed in to that method when you want a cell of that type.

Comment: I am just loading static cells from the storyboard file. Its not a programatically built tableview , so I am not using cellforRowAtIndex path , just using viewDidLoad to assign values to IBOutlets to the TableViewController itself. Can you please give an example?

Comment: @real19 I don't know if that can be done with a static table view. Is there a reason why you can't use dynamic prototypes?

Comment: The only reason I didn't want to use dynamic prototypes was so that I have to code less and its simpler